# snuggle up to someone

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the exact meaning of "snuggle up to" in the following sentence? It is about an abortive attempt to removal someone called Mosadeq.
We now have to take a whole new look at the situation and probably have to snuggle up to Mosadeq if we’re going to save anything there.

Comment: I assume you've found [the literal definition](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snuggle+up) *- to cuddle up close to someone or something* (usually, signifying genuine relaxed affection). I'm more used to [cosy up to](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cosy-up-to-sb), which in BrE is much more closely associated with the metaphoric sense *to be very friendly to someone with the hope of getting an advantage* than it is with the original/literal meaning.

Answer (score 1):

This idiom "**[snuggle up (to someone or something)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snuggle+up)**" means "**to cuddle up close to someone or something**"

Here's a [**Cambridge definition**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snuggle):

> **to move yourself into a warm and comfortable position, especially one in which your body is against another person or covered by something.**

I've done a little research and may suggest that it metaphorically means "**to get into very close relationship with that person ([to suck up to him](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/suck-up-to-sb))**"

Comment: I don't see the point of posting just that easily-obtained definition - surely OP would have found that for himself already? The issue here is that (so far as I'm aware) the *metaphoric* sense rarely occurs with this specific phrasing, so it won't normally be explicitly defined in most dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

To **snuggle up to** someone means to get your body physically close to theirs, often in an amorous situation, e.g. kissing on the sofa in front of a fire.

The phrase is from the semantic realm of personal (amorous) relationships, but here we're talking international power politics, and so we must understand the term figuratively: some sort of *cozy* relationship must be established with Mosadeq. That could involve putting money in a secret bank account or offering favors and incentives of other kinds, in general, things that would put the gift-giver on good terms with the person. In some instances, it might even involve actual 'cuddling', if you get my drift. Wild sex parties are not unheard of. The "corridors of power" are often hotel bedrooms.

Compare it to "They *got into bed with* the dictator during the 1960's". But there it's figurative.